# My new pages appear with Sorry, we couldn't find the page you were looking for

Tags: control-panel

I am adding new entries to my site and following the exact same blueprint as the rest of my pages.

However I cannot make any edits to the the new pages and when I attempt to preview them it appears: Sorry, we couldn't find the page you were looking for.

Can you help please?

Best,
Jack

Comment: Not a lot to go on here... what version of Craft is this? "Sorry, we couldn't find the page you were looking for." isn't a string in Craft itself, so do you have any plugins installed? Or is that coming from your web server? Do you only get that message if you're using Live Preview or do you get it on the front-end of the site as well?

Comment: Sorry Brad,

Version is Craft CMS 2.7.2 

I am getting the message on the entry itself, I cannot access Live Preview on this entry.

I have essentially created a Single Section type and added two pre-existing Field Blocks which work on other entries.

https://planesavercu.co.uk/employer-information

Comment: https://planesavercu.co.uk/employer-information is your 404 page, probably defined as 404.html in your templates folder.  That just means that Craft can't figure out which template to render when https://planesavercu.co.uk/employer-information is request.  I'd check your section's settings as a starting point for that page.